# Store large dataframes in redis through R

Tags: r, redis, dataframe

I have a number of large dataframes in R which I was planning to store using redis. I am totally new to redis but have been reading about it today and have been using the R package `rredis`.

I have been playing around with small data and saved and retrieved small dataframes using the `redisSet()` and `redisGet()` functions. However when it came to saving my larger dataframes (the largest of which is 4.3 million rows and 365MB when saved as .RData file)
using the code `redisSet('bigDF', bigDF)` I get the following error message:

```
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
  ERR Protocol error: invalid bulk length
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In writeBin(v, con) : problem writing to connection
2: In writeBin(.raw("\r\n"), con) : problem writing to connection
```

Presumably because the dataframe is too large to save. I know that redisSet writes the dataframe as a string, which is perhaps not the best way to do it with large dataframes. Does anyone know of the best way to do this?

EDIT: I have recreated the error my creating a very large dummy dataframe:

```
bigDF <- data.frame(
'lots' = rep('lots',40000000),
'of' = rep('of',40000000),
'data' = rep('data',40000000),
'here'=rep('here',40000000)
)
```

Running `redisSet('bigDF',bigDF)` gives me the error:

```
 Error in .redisError("Invalid agrument") : Invalid agrument
```

the first time, then running it again immediately afterwards I get the error

```
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
  ERR Protocol error: invalid bulk length
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In writeBin(v, con) : problem writing to connection
2: In writeBin(.raw("\r\n"), con) : problem writing to connection
```

Thanks

Comment: Share the actual code you are using in a formatted code block. It will make it much easier for someone with experience to diagnose and suggest adjustments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In short:** you cannot. [Redis can store a maximum of 512 Mb of data in a String value](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) and your serialized demo data frame is bigger than that:

```
> length(serialize(bigDF, connection = NULL)) / 1024 / 1024
[1] 610.352
```

---

**Technical background:**

`serialize` is called in the `.cerealize` function of the package via `redisSet` and `rredis:::.redisCmd`:

```
> rredis:::.cerealize
function (value) 
{
    if (!is.raw(value)) 
        serialize(value, ascii = FALSE, connection = NULL)
    else value
}
<environment: namespace:rredis>
```

---

*Offtopic:* why would you store such a big dataset in redis anyway? Redis is for small key-value pairs. On the other hand I had some success storing big R datasets in [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) (with GridFS) by adding the compressed `RData` there as an attachement.

Comment: Thanks daroczig, so just to clarify you're query length(serialize(... gives the size of the string value in Mb? I suppose I could split the dataframe in 2 and save it separately but given your final comment I assume you wouldn't recommend that? With regards to your question I have only just started using redis so wasn't aware of its limitations in storing large datasets, I had heard it was a good way of storing and retrieving data quickly so was just taking a look at it. I will look into CouchDB and MongoDB as well.

Comment: The optimal storage for your R datasets really depends on your needs. redis is damn fast of course as it's supposed to store everything in memory, that's why you should rather only store as much data there that fit in your physical memory. On the other hand, if you only access that data on localhost, then there is no need for a DB backend: create a RAM-disk and write `RData` there in a jiffy and reload that at any time. You should also figure out the optimal compression method and ratio (CPU vs IO). If you use multiple computers, then choose your DB on your needs like replication, sharding etc

Comment: @daroczig, your above post omits other needs why one would want to store larger items in Redis, keyword: data exchange. One might generate larger data items in C# and store in Redis in order to easily access in R or the other way around. Sure, if one just wanted to store in R generated data and re-access later in R then storing to disk is the best solution, possibly in combination with memory mapped files. But using Redis makes a lot of sense to exchange data when the locations between source and target of data are not shared and Redis is the only point of exchange.

Comment: @MattWolf there might be some extreme (and IMHO insane) situations where Redis would an optimal solution for data exchange (of huge data stored as blob in a key-value DB), but it's hard to envision :)

Comment: @daroczig, I disagree, just 2 examples: a) a constantly changing dataset (either through appends over overwrites). It would be very cumbersome to maintain such through file I/O. Much better to just update the value with known key in Redis, plus you have the benefit of publishing an update notification that can be consumed by anyone having access to Redis. b) unless you hit the limits of Redis or physical memory there is no reason why having to go through files. 4.3 million rows is nothing, if the data is too large it can be easily broken up into parts.

Comment: We are living in the age of distributed computing, and file I/O locks you into operations on the same physical machine unless of course you want to write a file I/O server and clients. Redis can be distributed anywhere and I currently use it for inter proc messaging as well as key/value store of non-persisted items (though it can be persisted). So, I would say if the asker only wants to write and read the same data on the same machine, file I/O is to be preferred, but for other situations a shared db should be preferred of which I include Redis.

Comment: @MattWolf thanks for the explanation, although I still think that using redis in the examples is suboptimal. Beside redis and disk, there are bunch of other great tools in the open-source community (SQL, NoSQL and e.g. message queues) - thanks God and the hackers, I am not sure why you think I want to store data on disk `xor` in redis. Anyway, sorry for the off-topic thread here.

Comment: @daroczig, I appreciate your sharing your thoughts, its just I feel we are talking in circles: You just mentioned NoSQL among other solutions. Sure document DBs may be a solution, but so are key/value stores (of which Redis is one) and it depends on the specific data structure of the asker which one is to be preferred. Just wanted to add from my own experience using Redis. There are some excellent packages that co-operate with R and Redis, not just rredis. I am sure you know full well the time difference to develop a proper setup in SQL vs. document or key/value stores. I respect your choice